# Navigation Drawer does not open when I use ViewPager as Fragment

Tags: android

I had scenario where NavigationDrawer does not popup when I use ViewPager as Fragment which itself is launched when I click one of the NavigationDrawer items.I am using material design where both my NavigationDrawer and ViewPager both are fragments. My Code  is as b

```
   package com.andr.viewpager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.FragmentDrawer;
import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.FriendsFragment;
import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.HomeFragment;
import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.MessagesFragment;
import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;

public class ViewPagerFagment extends Fragment{
     private ViewPager mPager;
     private View view;
     private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
     private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_screen_slide, container, false);
         mPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
         mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        return view;
    }


     /**
         * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
         * sequence.
         */
        private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
            public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                 switch(position) {

                 case 0: return new MessagesFragment();
                 case 1: return  new HomeFragment();
                 case 2: return new FriendsFragment();
                 default: return new FriendsFragment();
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return NUM_PAGES;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }


}
```

NavigationDrawer fragment:

```
    package com.andr.navdrawerdemo;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.andr.adapter.NavigationDrawerAdapter;
import com.andr.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;



public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private com.andr.adapter.NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

My  Individual Fragments:

```
    package com.andr.navdrawerdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;


public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
    }
}


package com.andr.navdrawerdemo;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

```
package com.andr.navdrawerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;


public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {


    public MessagesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

my mainActivity

```
package com.andr.navdrawerdemo;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andr.navdrawerdemo.R;
import com.andr.viewpager.ViewPagerFagment;

//http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /* mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);*/

        initializeSlidingMenu();
    }

    public void initializeSlidingMenu(){
           mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

           setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

           drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
           drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
           drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

           // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
           displayView(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.action_search){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
            displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FriendsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MessagesFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ViewPagerFagment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_slider);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

// my layouts

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context="com.andr.navdrawerdemo.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.andr.navdrawerdemo.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Viewpager layout

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Can anyone help me y my slidingmenu does n't popup in ViewPAger fragment

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ViewPager should be inside the main layout. I'm still struggling with making this work 100%, but by doing:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="thehighestprimenumber.com.losprincipios.ChapterActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/containerBox" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ListView android:id="@+id/drawer"
    ...
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This way the navigationDrawer opens.

My problem is, when I click on an item on the Navigation Drawer, the fragment doesn't update.

if you know how to solve this, you'd make my day =)